# how to remove outer element of AJAX XML Response

Tags: jquery, xml, dom

Scenario: I wish to return a list of elements via AJAX back to browser. Using JAXB for the marshalling and due to XML requiring a root element (which JSON does not...) I wrapped my list inside an envelope (wrapper) element. Now on client side (browser), I wish to remove the outside element leaving the list of elements inside intact. I then wish to put the extracted list of elements into the HTML Dom. How can I do this?

Example for clarification:

Wished to send:

```
<tr><td>data</td></tr><tr><td>data</td></tr>
```

Due to restrictions on text/xml response type (in order to comply with XML), I wrapped this as:

```
<tbody><tr><td>data</td></tr><tr><td>data</td></tr></tbody>
```

So in my jquery callback method I receive the above (as xml object). How can I (in no particular order except whatever works) remove the tbody element, and ensure the remaining tr tags are acceptable domData. I played with find(), filter() etc but still no solution that addresses both requirements.

Thank you to everyone who has already replied! This one was really troubling me. Without testing all the supplied answers, it would appear there are multiple ways to do this and likely the answers each could be marked as the correct one. I actually went with this:

```
 }).done(function(xmlResponse) {
    $strData = xmlToString(xmlResponse);
    $html = $($strData);
    $('#mytable tbody').html($html.contents());
 });
```

For some reason, without the explicit callout to convert the xml to a string first, it didn't work. Thereafter, wrapping the string inside $() coerced it to be DOM conformant, and then the contents() method took care of the extraction (removal) of the outer element.

Here is the xmlToString() method. If anyone can point out how I can remove the need for this ugly method then that would definitely be a bonus. It looks like something out of a pre 2009 html application:

```
function xmlToString(xmlData) { 
  var xmlString;
  if (window.ActiveXObject){
     xmlString = xmlData.xml;
  } else{
     xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
  }
  return xmlString;
}
```

I will mark the first answer I read as correct on basis that it was enough to get me over the finish line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `.contents()` to extract the contents of your root element:

```
$html = $('<tbody><tr><td>data</td></tr><tr><td>data</td></tr></tbody>');
$html.contents().appendTo('#something-else');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$(xml).find('tbody').contents().unwrap();
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/wGqKc/)

Comment: Mohammad - thank you for your helpful suggestion. Your example didn't run when I tried it in jsFiddle: If I comment out the line you gave above then it runs ok. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just find the children of the tbody. Imagining the 'data' variable contains the data received via ajax:

```
var $shard = $(data).children();

$('.something').append($shard);
```

Explained:

```
$(data) // creates the dom shard.
$(data).children(); // selects it's children, which is everything except the tbody
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) to replace it with it's children (that'll keep them):

```
$(xml).children("tbody").replaceWith($(xml).children("tbody").children());
```