# how to remove outer element of AJAX XML Response - Part 2

Tags: jquery, xml, dom

Ok, this one has beaten me fair and square. Need help as I've wasted hours on this one. Please see my same question, answered earlier, but now proven not to actually do what I wanted - [how to remove outer element of AJAX XML Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091718/how-to-remove-outer-element-of-ajax-xml-response)

Scenario: Server side sends client browser a text/xml response payload as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><tbody><tr data-tt-parent-id="" data-tt-id="12345678" data-tt-branch="false"><td><span class="file">Total</span></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr></tbody>
```

I need that cleansed of the XML markup header, and stripped of the tbody outer element, and acceptable as DOM compliant HTML to be inserted into the tbody of a table with id="tree".

To Clarify, I require:

```
<tr data-tt-parent-id="" data-tt-id="12345678" data-tt-branch="false"><td><span class="file">Total</span></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr> as compliant HTML that will work with .html() or .append() etc
```

I would ideally like to leverage a JQuery solution but right now pure javascript would still be acceptable to get this thing done.

This problem has really bugged the heck out of me. Please help me understand where I am clearly going wrong on this. I tried various combinations given from the previous question related to this same issue. Thank you all for any assistance. I acknowledge I am not a jquery veteran yet.

Comment: which is the outer element? is it the `tbody`

Comment: sorry Arun, got hidden because I wrote it inside open close tags. The outer element is the tbody - question updated. thanks for asking.

Comment: What I need is: <tr data-tt-parent-id="" data-tt-id="12345678" data-tt-branch="false"><td><span class="file">Total</span></td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr> as HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(data).find('tbody').contents();
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qwtOmXXJMzohVQuO9zmZ?p=preview)

Ex:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'data.xml',
    datatype: 'xml'
}).done(function(data){
    $('table').append($(data).find('tbody').contents())
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I did to get this to work. Caveat this with the fact that I really liked the solution Arun provided but for reason (despite everything looking great in debugger) it just didn't update the DOM correctly in my case (modern firefox). So here is the ugly approach I took:

```
$.ajax({
    async : false, 
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    url : "/topnodes" 
}).done(function(xmlResponse) {
    $strData = xmlToString(xmlResponse);
    $out = $strData.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>', "");
    $out = $out.replace('<tbody>', "");
    $out = $out.replace('</tbody>', "");
    var rows = $($out).filter("tr");
    $('#tree tbody').html(rows);
   // do other stuff...
});
```

I had to convert this thing out of XML world back into something standard jquery world could handle hence the use of the convenience xmlToString() method (see previous post). Then just filter out the tr elements and place inside tbody using html().

Arun's approach all looked great right up to the point where .html() is called and then just failed to update the DOM. As follows:

```
$.ajax({
    async : false, 
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    url : "/topnodes" 
}).done(function(xmlResponse) {
   var rows = $(xmlResponse).find('tbody').contents();
   $('#tree tbody').html(rows);
   // do other stuff...
});
```

Arun - if you are still reading this post and know how I can use the above (avoiding all this string replacement and xml to string method calling etc, I would be really interested if you could share this info with me. Thank you for your valued contribution.

I won't mark this as the correct answer for now in case there is a cleaner way to get the result. But it does work if anyone out there is hard pressed for a similar solution.